# disabling OB2269 burst mode

Tags: power-supply, pwm

I have a powersupply which uses the OB2269 chip for PWM generation.
It has a "burst mode" to limit standby power usage, but I dont need it, and in my application its harmful. Is there a way to disable Burstmode? from the datasheet, the only way I see is to hold the feedback line above 1.8V at all times. could this be possible? I guess not, because the voltage would also change?

Comment: Skimming through it, it seems to be the case, I don't know how, but it seems

Comment: Datasheet says >1.2 Volts.  But is this an X/Y problem?  Why use this regulator if it is not suitable for your application?  Also consider adjusting feedback so that the output is 2 Volts higher than desired, and use a linear regulator after it.

Comment: The only chance I see is to add a dummy load, not a nice solution.

Comment: yeah, I never found a way to do this. Only solution is to change out the OB2269 to another chip. thanks for the answers!